# Swap two excel columns in VB script

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have to copy data from one excel file to another. But the thing is that I have to swap two column data before I paste it in the destination.

I am very new to VB script and would love to hear from you guys regarding how to proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a two dimensional array.

Comment: If I understand it well, you have to swap two columns in an Excel Sheet, let's say `Sheet1`, then copy the entire `Sheet1` and paste it into a second sheet of another workbook ?

Comment: Nope. I have `Sheet1` and lets say two columns  `ColA` and then `ColB`. I want to swap the data from `ColB` to `ColA`.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it.
But you could have found this by recording a macro.

```
Sub Swap_Columns()
'Replace A:A with one your swapping
'C:C needs to be a blank column you can use to move the data
'Replace B:B with your other Column
'Replace Sheet1 with your sheet name
    Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:A").Cut Destination:=Columns("C:C")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:B").Cut Destination:=Columns("A:A")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("C:C").Cut Destination:=Columns("B:B")
End Sub
```

If you want to use it on separate sheets put this in a module then you can call the Swap macro from anywhere on you workbook.

```
Sub Swap()
Dim ws As String
ws = Application.ActiveSheet.Name
    Sheets(ws).Columns("A:A").Cut Destination:=Columns("C:C")
    Sheets(ws).Columns("B:B").Cut Destination:=Columns("A:A")
    Sheets(ws).Columns("C:C").Cut Destination:=Columns("B:B")
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay  This is what I'm doing.

Comment: `Sheets(Worksheet.Name).Columns("AK:AK").Cut Destination:=Columns("AU:AU")
    Sheets(Worksheet.Name).Columns("AJ:AJ").Cut Destination:=Columns("AK:AK")
    Sheets(Worksheet.Name).Columns("AU:AU").Cut Destination:=Columns("AJ:AJ")`

And yet I get error. Anything that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Its because of the Worksheet.name bit, can't you just put the worksheet name in quotes instead or is there a reason you need to do it like this.

Comment: I have the worksheet object so I thought I could use it. And this code handles many files so I was looking at it in that angle. will try with the hard coded name

Comment: if not you could put this before the code "ws = Application.ActiveSheet.Name" then replace worksheet.name with "ws"

Comment: I've added to my answer

Comment: are you using any autofilters in the sheets? Just tested and this code does not work with autofilter unless you unfilter them

Comment: We are not using any autofilters. I'm skeptical about the way I'm giving the column entry... is that a possibility.